# Libgdx TouchListner on gameObjects (Phone Screen)

Tags: java, android, input, libgdx

I have a problem with my TouchListener on a Libgdx game.

On my Gamerenderer I have this:

```js
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Vector3 input;

    private Array<Objects> objects;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    
    //In Constructor
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, Configuration.screenWidth, Configuration.screenHeight);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    objects = myGame.Objects();
    input = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    
    //My Renderer
    public void render(float runtime){
        Gdx.app.log("GameRenderer: ", "Render()");

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        input.x = Gdx.input.getX();
        input.y = Gdx.input.getY();
        camera.unproject(input);
        batch.begin();

        for (Objects object:objects) {
                                object.getFont().draw(batch,object.getGlyphLayout(),object.getX(),object.getY());
            object.getRec().set(object.getX(),object.getY(),object.getGlyphLayout().width,object.getGlyphLayout().height);
            if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
                Gdx.app.log("Clicked", "Touched");
                if(object.getRec().contains(input.x, input.y)) {
                        Gdx.app.log("Clicked", "Great");
                    }
                    else {
                        Gdx.app.log("Clicked", "Noooooooooooo");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        batch.end();
    }
```

When I run my game it's working fine except the touchlistener sometimes work fine but after several secondes from the touch.

the Gdx.app.log("Clicked", "Touched"); is fired with the touch.

but the Gdx.app.log("Clicked", "Great"); OR the Gdx.app.log("Clicked", "Noooooooooooo"); i must perform a long press until the touch is fired.

Thank You

## Edit

I added a ShapeRenderer to see what exactely my objects do like that:

```js
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        for(Objects object:objects) {
            shapeRenderer.setColor(255 / 255.0f, 0 / 255.0f, 0 / 255.0f, 1);
            shapeRenderer.rect(object.getRec().x, object.getRec().y, object.getRec().width, object.getRec().height);

            shapeRenderer.setColor(0 / 255.0f, 0 / 255.0f, 255 / 255.0f, 1);
            shapeRenderer.rect(object.getX(), object.getY(), object.getGlyphLayout().width, object.getGlyphLayout().height);
        }
        shapeRenderer.end();
```

Then I have this result:

[image]

The Black Rectangle is the object and the Blue one is the ShapeRenderer of the object on top of ShapeRenderer of object's Rectangle.

Now when I click on the object it don't fire the click, but when I click on the ShapeRenderer it fire it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I solved it, just in case if someone have the same problem it has been located at:

```js
object.getRec().set(object.getX(),object.getY(),object.getGlyphLayout().width,object.getGlyphLayout().height);
```

I replaced **object.getY()**

with **object.getY()-object.getGlyphLayout().height**

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution :

```
@Override
public void create() {
    // Codes
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter () {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            // Insert your code
            return true;
        }
    }
    );
    //Codes
}
```

Putting ***Gdx.input.isTouched()*** inside the loop is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank You I have already change my touchListener to a class that implement InputProcessor but It didn't solve the problem.